# How to setup subdomain/domain with and without www prefix on localhost

Tags: apache2, vhosts, hosts

I went through lots of SO questions but non is giving me the right answer .

I have  following config in apache vhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "D:/Web Server/xampp/htdocs/testsite/frontend/www"
    ServerName mydomain.com
    ServerAlias www.mydomain.com
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "D:/Web Server/xampp/htdocs/testsite/backend/www"
    ServerName admin.mydomain.com
    ServerAlias www.admin.mydomain.com
</VirtualHost>
```

AND hosts file :

```
127.0.0.1               testsite.com
127.0.0.1               admin.testsite.com
```

What I need is that:

www.testsite.com and testsite.com should point to same thing

and same with

www.admin.testsite.com and admin.testsite.com

What is the issue with this config ?
Do I need to add separate records for each , one with www and other without www ?

please help me sort this issue

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the www. versions of your domains to your etc hosts.

```
127.0.0.1               testsite.com www.testsite.com
127.0.0.1               admin.testsite.com www.admin.testsite.com
```

Comment: I upvoted, but are multiple entries on one line actually allowed (on Windows, or other OSes for that matter)? That would actually be a novelty for me, which I wish I'd have known earlier. :)

Comment: working in windows right now with multiple entries on single line :), I just knew that

Comment: @sakhunzai Thanks! I'm going to give it a try later on (not on my Windows box right now). Still working with XP here though. What flavour are you working with?

Comment: @sakhunzai Ok, thanks once again. I'll find out soon enough whether this works with XP too, I guess. :)

Answer (score 1):

Using CNAMEs makes your DNS data easier to manage.  CNAME-records point back to an A record. So if you change the IP address of the A record, all your CNAME records pointed to that record automatically follow the new IP of the A record. The alternative solution is to have multiple A records, but then you would have multiple places to change the IP address which increases the chances of error.

The most popular use of the CNAME-record, is to provide access to a web server using both the standard www.domain.com and domain.com (without the www). This is usually done by adding a CNAME-record for the www name pointing to the short name [while creating an A Record for the short name (without www)].
Example:

You have a website with the domain name mywebsite.nl. This domain name is hooked up to an A-record which translates the domain name to the appropriate IP address, f.i. `11.22.33.444`.

You also have several subdomains, like www.mywebsite.nl, ftp.mywebsite.nl, mail.mywebsite.nl etc. and you want this sub domains to point to your main domain name mywebsite.nl. In stead of creating A-records for each sub domain and binding it to the IP address of your domain, you create an alias, a CNAME-record. See the table below, in case your IP address changes, you only have to edit 1 A-record and all subdomains follow automatically because de CNAMES point to the main domain with the A-record.

```
(Sub)domain
Type
Target
mywebsite.nl

A
11.22.33.444
www.mywebsite.nl

CNAME
mywebsite.nl
ftp.mywebsite.nl

CNAME
mywebsite.nl
mail.mywebsite.nl

CNAME
mywebsite.nl
```